# How to open ports not only locally?

Tags: networking

I am trying to open a port on my VPS (Ubuntu) in order to play around with some network related programming. I am using UFW and I cannot seem to open port 2794 for non-local connections. I have added the rule "ufw allow from any to any port 2794 proto tcp" but it foes not want to work for some reason.

When I start my simple server to listen at port 2794 for connections and I run nmap (nmap -p 2794 127.0.0.1) I get the following output when run from the VPS:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
2794/tcp open  unknown
```

This shows the port is open at least for local connection. But when I run nmap (nmap -p 2794 <IP>) from my desktop home I get:

```
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
2794/tcp closed unknown
```

Also, I successfully run an Nginx server from it as I see content when I view the IP/site in Firefox, meaning port 80 and 22 are open for outside connections. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the firewall is the problem here? There could be some other problem.

Maybe your simple server is only listening on localhost (`127.0.0.1` in IPv4, or `::1` in IPv6). That would explain your nmap results. You can check this using `ss`. Grab yourself a terminal and do a `ss -ltn | grep 2794`. If the fourth column (which is the column 'Local Address:Port') reads something like `127.0.0.1:2794` or `[::1]:2794`, your simple server is listening on localhost only.

If this is the case, you have several options. You could use a proxy server to forward traffic from the Internet to your simple server. You could use an `iptables` rule to forward the TCP connection. Or (and this is probably the easiest option) you could change your simple server so it listens on all interfaces. Do this by specifying it should listen on `0.0.0.0` (IPv4) or `::` (IPv6).

Comment: You were 100% correct! My network knowledge is unfortunately not that great yet, so I'm playing with my VPS more than a little bit (configured a postfix + dovecot mail server, whoohoo!). I had no clue about 0.0.0.0, only 127.0.0.1 and thought I had to listen on that address, not knowing I would then only listen for my own connections. Thanks a bunch, you're my hero of the week!